# MySql group average and group last value in one query

Tags: mysql

I have table named **Amounts** with columns *RowId*, *CounterId* and *Amount*. It is easy to group by *CounterId* and get counters average value, but if I want also to get last value of *Amount* in group to know is it bigger or smaller than average, I’m in trouble? How to get that as just including *Amount* in query gives me first value of *Amount* in group what is useless. Maybe it is easy to do, but I have not found answer for my problem with just one table. I found, how to find only last *Amount* in group by help with *RowId*, but how to obtain them - average and last value - to one result, is mystery for me now… Thanks ahead.

---

Thanks to Ram Bath I built what I needed and result is here:

```
SELECT      Kliendid.Id        AS Id,
            Kliendid.Nimi      AS Klient,
            MIN(X.Tarbimine)   AS Piseim,
            AVG(X.Tarbimine)   AS Keskmine,
            MAX(X.Tarbimine)   AS Suureim,
            COUNT(X.Tarbimine) AS Kuid,
            (
              Select Tarbimine 
              from Naidud A 
              where A.Id=MAX(X.Id)
            ) as Viimane 
FROM        Naidud X 
INNER JOIN  Kliendid ON Kliendid.ID=X.Klient
INNER JOIN  Mooturid ON Mooturid.ID=X.Mootur
WHERE       X.Tarbimine>0
     AND    X.Aeg>'2015-12-31'
     AND    Mooturid.Kasutusel=1
GROUP BY    X.Mootur
HAVING      Kuid>5
     AND    (Viimane=Piseim OR Viimane=Suureim)
```

As you see, my question was simplified as I use Estonian for table and column names and there would be much harder to help if I had shared code from the beginning... Thanks again for all of you.

Comment: Share your code here please.

Comment: SO what have you done so for, using that we could guide you

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming you RowId is Unique or is the Primary Key.

```
SELECT RowId,AVG(AmountId) as Average_Amount,(Select Amount from Amounts a where a.RowId=MAX(X.RowId)) as LastAmount from Amounts X Group by X.CounterId;
```

Comment: Thanks! As I quite raw in SQL queries, your kindness helped me to road again.

Comment: I allready accepted it at first day, but system says something that votes from me - with less than 15 user points - saved, but can not be shown before my reputation grows. :)